# SQL select value if condition in same table is met

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, case

I am looking to get values from a table when a value is present, otherwise have NULL (or a placeholder) instead.
How can I do this?

The tables look like this:

```
Students
| ID | Firstname | Lastname |
|----|-----------|----------|
| 1  | John      | Doe      |
| 2  | Jane      | Frost    |
| 3  | Rob       | Smith    |
```

```
StudyYear
| ID | StartDate               | EndDate                 |CurrentYear|
|----|-------------------------|-------------------------|-----------|
| 1  | 2018-09-01 00:00:00.000 | 2019-08-31 00:00:00.000 | Year1     |
| 1  | 2019-09-01 00:00:00.000 | 2020-08-31 00:00:00.000 | Year2     |
| 1  | 2020-09-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021-08-31 00:00:00.000 | Year3     |
| 3  | 2020-09-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021-08-31 00:00:00.000 | Year1     |
```

My desired result is this:

```
| ID | Firstname | Lastname |CurrentYear|
|----|-----------|----------|-----------|
| 1  | John      | Doe      | Year3     |
| 2  | Jane      | Frost    | NULL      |
| 3  | Rob       | Smith    | Year1     |
|    |           |          |           |
```

I have tried several things with a CASE:

```
(
    CASE
        WHEN (
            YEAR(StudyYear.CurrentYear) = '2020'
        ) THEN (SELECT StudyYear WHERE YEAR(StudyYear.CurrentYear) = '2020')
        ELSE (NULL)
    END
) AS CurrentYear
```

But that filters out the entries that do not appear in studyyear table.
Not doing a case returns all results from the other table as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using OUTER APPLY

```
SELECT 
 S.*, O.CurrentYear 

FROM Students S
OUTER APPLY 
( 
SELECT CurrentYear FOM StudyYear SY
WHERE SY.ID=S.ID AND
YEAR(StartDate)=2020
)O
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below -

```
select id, Firstname,Lastname,currentyear
from Students s left join StudyYear s1
on s.id=s1.id and YEAR(startdate)=2020 and year(enddate)>=2020
```

Answer (score 1):

use subquery and join

```
select a.id,a.firstname,a.lastname,CurrentYear
 from students a left join
(
select *,row_number()(over partition by id order by EndDate desc)
rn from studyyear
) b on a.id=b.id
 where a.rn=1
```